Google FCM problems with user that have multiple devics
I have some curious problems with Google Firebase Cloud Messaging and sending notifications:

An Android app is receiving notifications via FCM. It is installed on two devices (smartphone and tablet) of one user. He uses the same Google-Account for both devices.

Both app-installations have their unique FCM token.


My Problem: I can't send notifications successfully to both FCM tokens!
Only sending to one token succeeds, sending to the other tokens returns 404 "Not registered".
getToken() in the app returns all the time the same token.
Which device/token can receive notifications changes from time to time, its either device 1 or device 2.
I've further investigated that behaviour and could see the following:

The device where the app was most recently installed/updated can receive notifications, sending to the token of the other device return 404 unregistered.

Updating one device seem to invalidate the token on the other device.
When the user updates the app on first device, its token will become valid again, but that invalidates the token of the second device on the FCM server. When the user updates the app on the second device, its token will become valid again, but that invalidates the token of the first device.
My questions:
According to Google documentation a token that returns "404 Not registered" will never be valid again? I can see a different behaviour?!
Why can't I send notifications to a token that was returned by getToken() in the android app?
Is there a FCM connection between multiple devices in a google account?
Anybody have some ideas regarding this topic?

Sure, here is a clearer version of the text you provided:
I encountered the same problem, and here's how I resolved it:
Whenever a user logs in from any device, I retrieve their FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) token and store it in Firebase in a collection called "fcmTokens". I use the user's email or UID as an identifier to manage to whom I should send notifications. I store multiple FCM tokens for each user and use a loop to send notifications to all of a person's devices.
For example:
in my firebase I stored fcm tokens like this
fcmTokens (collection)
  - UID/Email (document)
    - fcm token 1 (field)
    - fcm token 2 (field)

This is how I save multiple FCM tokens and then use a loop to retrieve a specific user's tokens and send notifications to each one.
Tip: When a user logs out from any device, I delete the FCM token of that device in the logout function.

Thanks.
I think my problem is different to your anwser. I can store all tokens, every device has a unique token. I know whích device belongs to which token. 99% percent of devices/tokens work as expected.
But that described special case doesn't work how I understood FCM:
One user has two devices under his Play store account. I can't send to both devices at the same time. One of the two unique tokens seem always to be invalid (FCM returns 404 not registered).
Updating one device seem to invalidate the token on the other device. When the user updates the app on first device, its token will become valid again, but that invalidates the token of the second device.
When the user updates the app on the second device, its token will become valid again, but that invalidates the token of the first device.
